# mongodb / javascript variable in query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have:

```
var optiontable = {1: 'attack', 2: 'defence', 3: 'intelligence'};
    var option = 1;
    var minion = minions[thisminion]; // get correct, works.
    console.log(optiontable[option]); // would output "attack"
    var nameoption = optiontable[option];
var increasement = 8;
```

how would i do to get the minion.attack based on:

```
thisminion.nameoption  // this wont work when it should display the result of thisminion.attack
```

and get the nameoption to use in:

```
      minions.update({
                    _id: thisminion._id,
                    userid: playerid
                }, {$inc: {nameoption: increasement}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without looking at the rest of the code, but looks like you just need to change

```
thisminion.nameoption
```

to

```
thisminion[nameoption]
```

Since your original line is trying to access thisminion's property called 'nameoption'. Using square brackets would access the property named the same as the value of nameoption.

As for the mongo part: since you can't use a variable as left-hand value, you need to do a little bit of extra work:

```
var updateObj = {};
updateObj[nameoption] = increasement;
```

then you can do this:

```
 minions.update({
                    _id: thisminion._id,
                    userid: playerid
                }, {$inc: updateObj})
```

Similar questions:

[How to set mongo field from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362401/how-to-set-mongo-field-from-variable)

[Using variables in MongoDB update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503656/using-variables-in-mongodb-update-statement)

Comment: but thisminion.attack is the correct one. i need it to work with the variable.

Comment: I have updated my answer after re-reading your question. Sorry for that.